# CocoaPods iOS Framework Linking i386 Files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I am having problems trying to link frameworks into a test project of mine...

I do understand, mostly, how CocoaPods work, and the reasons I am trying to link the actual frameworks from these files is beyond the scope of this question.

In my CocoaPods "Podfile", I have the following.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'


target 'GasAPI' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!

    pod "Alamofire"
    pod "SwiftyJSON"

    target 'GasAPITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths

        # Pods for testing

        pod "Alamofire"
        pod "SwiftyJSON"
    end
end
```

But, any time I do a "pod install", if I go the Project settings of the "Pods" project, the "Base SDK" changes to "Latest OS X".

[image: Pods project with wrong architecture]

I have made sure that all of the "Targets" have "Latest iOS (iOS 9.3) as their Base SDK.

However, when I try to link one of these files into my test project, I get a linker error that appears to me like it is looking for an OS X library, and not an iOS library.

Here is the latest error that I got:

```
Ld /Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GasApiTestProject2.app/GasApiTestProject2 normal i386
    cd /Users/brent/Dropbox/NJVC/API/GasApiTestProject2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Intermediates/GasApiTestProject2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GasApiTestProject2.build/Objects-normal/i386/GasApiTestProject2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Intermediates/GasApiTestProject2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GasApiTestProject2.build/Objects-normal/i386/GasApiTestProject2.swiftmodule -framework GasAPI -framework Result -framework SwiftyJSON -framework Moya -framework Alamofire -framework ReachabilitySwift -framework SwiftyBeaver -framework SwiftyRSA -framework Quick -framework Nimble -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Intermediates/GasApiTestProject2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GasApiTestProject2.build/Objects-normal/i386/GasApiTestProject2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/brent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GasAPI-gsmqzrqwzjzvuhdhmovzfhwbfbow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GasApiTestProject2.app/GasApiTestProject2

ld: framework not found Result
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried removing all Pods and rebuilding and re-adding them to the project, it still seems to want to default to OS X.

I am running Xcode v7.3.1 on OS X 10.11.6 and using CocoaPods v1.0.1

I have found lots of resources on how to link iOS & OS X projects, but that isn't the problem here.  It looks like my linker is looking for architectures that it shouldn't be.

What do I need to do to get past this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try clicking product, then hold down option, you will see clean turn into clean build folder and click that, then run project.

Comment: Thanks...  Tried it, didn't work.  I also tried going into my Derived Data folder and wiping all of that out.  Still no go.  Why is it looking for i386 libs?!

Comment: I know that SwiftyJSON has been going through some issue lately, try removing that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The i386 really had nothing to do with this issue, but it kind of acted like a red-herring and threw me off.

For the API that I am building, there was no "Copy Files" section.

So, in Xcode, under "Build Phases", I added a new "Copy Files" section and then chose "Frameworks" as the "Destination".  I added all of the frameworks that I needed, and everything worked!

Hope this helps anyone else who may run across this!

Perlguy.